# How to deal with multiple 400 response in Swagger 2.0

Tags: api, yaml, swagger

I have two cases for the 400 HTTP status code where the first response looks like this:

```
{
  "error": "No file uploaded!"
}
```

and the second response looks like this:

```
{
  "error": "Wrong file format. Endpoint only accepts images and pdf file formats!"
}
```

in swagger 2.0 yaml file definitions I documented the two responses in this way:

```
definitions:
     MultiError400:
        type: object
        properties:
          error:
            type: array
            items:
              enum:
              - $ref: '#/definitions/FirstError'
              - $ref: '#/definitions/SecondError'
      FirstError:
        type: string
        example: "No file uploaded!"
      SecondError:
        type: string
        example: "Wrong file format. Endpoint only accepts images and pdf file formats!"
```

and inside the endpoint I referred to it like this:

```
responses:
        "200":
          description: "Successful operation"
          schema:
            type: file
            example: image/png
        "400":
          description: Multiple 400 errors
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/MultiError400'
```

but when I tested it it gives me this undocumented error:

```
Undocumented
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: The second error message shouldn't return 400, but rather [415](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```yaml
produces:
  - "application/json"
responses:
  "400":
    description: ""
    schema:
      type: "object"
      properties:
        error:
          type: "string"
          description: >
            error:
             * `First Error` - No file uploaded!
             * `Second Error` - Endpoint only accepts images and pdf file formats!
          enum:
          - "No file uploaded!"
          - "Wrong file format. Endpoint only accepts images and pdf file formats!"
          default: "Wrong file format. Endpoint only accepts images and pdf file formats!"
```

You can set any `default` value form `enum` to show in <kbd>Example Value</kbd>, It will look like this:

[image]

---

Your <kbd>Model</kbd> View looks like this:

[image]

for more details refer https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-responses/

---

Hope this help.